# How to parse Javascript code in Javascript to get variable names not in current scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, scope, v8

```
var code = 'var n = a; x = y; status.show();\n// todo: \nconsole.log(xyz, "todo: // tests.", params);';
function parse (c) {
    var myFunc = new Function("myFunc", c); 
}
```

I'm using V8 NODEJS environment. So maybe it is possible to get information about declared variables and their scope of an existing function?

In fact I need the missing variable names `a`, `x`, `y`, `status`, `xyz` and `params`.
Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Best regards.

Comment: Not sure what you want to get. Does 'eval' fit you needs? I mean if you call 'eval(code)' inside 'parse' function, variables declared in 'code' will become local variables of 'parse'.

Comment: New Function is a form of eval. Usage of status will not declare it in scope... 
But you suggest something I forgot in my example. So I extend it with x = y;  :)

Comment: You could use the JS parser of UglifyJS, described [here](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/parser), to properly parse your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using some parser like [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or [esprima](http://esprima.org/) to parse the code, extract the variables and then test them in the current environment. I don't think that's very difficult to do that since I've built quite some JavaScript code analysis or compilation/evaluation.

But if you need a easier and faster solution, you can also try the [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). We can use it as a library, just disable other rules and leave only the "undefined variable". We can test each of the errors in the current environment  to see whether they're provided or not.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do it using [UglifyJS](https://www.google.com/search?q=uglifyjs):

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglifyjs");
var parsed = UglifyJS.parse(code);
parsed.figure_out_scope();
parsed.globals.each(function(g) {console.log(g.name)});
```

You can try this out by running `npm install uglifyjs` then `node` in a terminal. Copy and paste the `var code = (...);` bit from the question, then the code above; here is the result I get:

```
> parsed.globals.each(function(g) {console.log(g.name)});
a
x
y
status
console
xyz
params
```